# Javascript json object parsing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oOpenOrders = new Array();
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://192.168.19.22/test.php',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    alert(typeof(data.id));
                    oOpenOrders.push(data);
                }
               var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               debugger;
```

this code snippet i am using and want to parse it(want to use lat, long) even data.length say correct length 4 for following json, following json is coming from ajax call.:

```
[{"id":"3037","latitude":"28.617422000","longitude":"77.381180000"},
 {"id":"3036","latitude":"28.617422000","longitude":"77.381180000"},
 {"id":"3035","latitude":"28.617422000","longitude":"77.381180000"},
 {"id":"3034","latitude":"28.617422000","longitude":"77.381180000"}]
```

any idea ?

Comment: i want to save lat, long in a global array

Comment: `alert(data.id);` is alert undefined , and this where i am stucked

Comment: try ```data[i].id``` as you need the ith element

Comment: data is an array (of length 4), access an element by: `data[i].id`

Comment: it's working, thanks man. i am very new to js

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
alert(typeof data[i].id);
```